# Error adding `androidResources` no compress option to Android Library Gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to add the following option to my **gradle.kts** file for an Android Library

```
android{
        androidResources {
        noCompress += "tflite"
    }
}
```

But for some reason, whenever i try to Sync the project, I get this error

> - What went wrong:
>   class com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.AaptOptions$AgpDecorated_Decorated cannot be cast to class com.android.build.api.dsl.LibraryAndroidResources (com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.AaptOptions$AgpDecorated_Decorated and com.android.build.api.dsl.LibraryAndroidResources are in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @481a697b)

Anyone have any ideea how can i fix this? Internet seems to be of no use here.

Using the deprecated, older, version like this does not produce any error

```
aaptOptions{
    noCompress += "tflite"
}
```

I am using Android Gradle Plugin 8.1.0-beta05, with gradle wrapper 8.0, but behaved the same with AGP 8.1.0-beta04

This is the gradle.kts file:

```
@Suppress("DSL_SCOPE_VIOLATION") // TODO: Remove once KTIJ-19369 is fixed
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.com.android.library)
    alias(libs.plugins.org.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.mylibrary"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 26

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xcontext-receivers", "-Xexplicit-api=warning")
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources.excludes.add("META-INF/notice.txt")
    }
    androidResources {
        noCompress += "tflite"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and reported it. It seems to be fixed in the new version.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/294771624

> Fix is merged for 8.1.2, 8.2.0-beta03 and 8.3.0-alpha02

> Thank you for your patience while our engineering team worked to resolve this issue. A fix for this issue is now available in:
> Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Beta 3.
> Android Gradle Plugin 8.2.0-beta03

Answer (score 1):

It worked with me

```
 aaptOptions {
        noCompress  += "tflite"
        ignoreAssetsPattern = "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the latest update and A fix for this issue is available in:

- Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Beta 3
- Android Gradle Plugin 8.2.0-beta03

So use latest updates